# Match and subtract: one column to multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, replace, matching, subtraction

I have to two data tables, one with two columns and the other with multiple columns.

table1

```
Samples Val
a        2
b       58 
c        4
d      100
```

table2

```
Samples  A1    A2    A3
a       100    67     3
c        54    89   120
d        23    64    46
f         6    99    35
```

Now I have a big issue with that in R:

I would like to substract values of table2 from values (Val) of table1 when Samples match.
The final substracted values should replace those one in table2 (or in a new table row and column names should be the same as table2).
values < 0 should be replace by 0

The final table should look like that:

Final_table

```
Samples  A1    A2    A3
a        98    65     1
c        50    85   116
d         0     0     0
f         6    99    35
```

Can anyone please help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a vector that matches the sample names, then subtract:

```
x <- table1$Val[ match(table2$Samples, table1$Samples) ] 
# if sample doesn't match, then zero, nothing to subtract
x <- ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x)
x
# [1]   2   4 100   0

table2[, -1] <- table2[, -1] - x

# if negative then assign zero
table2[, -1][ table2[, -1] < 0 ] <- 0

table2
#   Samples A1 A2  A3
# 1       a 98 65   1
# 2       c 50 85 116
# 3       d  0  0   0
# 4       f  6 99  35
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dplyr` to check `across` the columns using an `ifelse` statement like this:

```r
library(dplyr)

table2 %>%
  left_join(., table1, by = "Samples") %>%
  mutate(across(A1:A3, ~ ifelse(!is.na(Val), .x - Val, .x))) %>%
  mutate(across(A1:A3, ~ ifelse(.x < 0 , 0, .x))) %>%
  select(-Val)
#>   Samples A1 A2  A3
#> 1       a 98 65   1
#> 2       c 50 85 116
#> 3       d  0  0   0
#> 4       f  6 99  35
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Data used:

```
table1 = read.table(text = "Samples Val
a        2
b       58 
c        4
d      100", header = TRUE)
 
table2 = read.table(text = "Samples  A1    A2    A3
a       100    67     3
c        54    89   120
d        23    64    46
f         6    99    35 ", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! My dataset is actually very large (I just only pick up an example from it). Actually table2 has 192 columns and 5097 rows  where table1 2 columns and 221 rows. I tried to do a vector for the columns name: subjects <- colnames(table2[2:192])  So that, I replace in your function (across(all_of(subjects), ~      But I am getting following error "Caused by error in `across()`:
! Can't compute column `A1`" Do you have an idea why it is not working?

Comment: Hi @ZubB, Do your columns have the same name as in your example? If not you should replace A1:A3 to the begin column and end column you want to subtract on.

Comment: If it's columns 2:192 you should be able to just do `across(2:192, ...)` - column positions like this has slightly less in-built error detection compared to using names but should work just fine if used with care.

Comment: @ZubB, Maybe you could share a more reproducible example in your question please?

Comment: Hi, I tried what you both suggested but neither A1:A191 or 2:192 doesn't work. I get always the same error.. I am not sure whether it is a problem of the tables. Those tables where matrix I transform into tables, everything looks fine but I have in both of them a column 0, which list  from1 to 5097.. maybe the across function can not deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively in `base r`

```r
merged_data <- merge(table2, table1, by = "Samples", all= TRUE)

merged_data$Val <- ifelse(!is.na(merged_data$Val),merged_data$Val,0)
merged_data[, -1] <- merged_data[, -1] - merged_data$Val
merged_data[, 5] <- NULL

merged_data <- merged_data[rowSums(!is.na(merged_data[, -1]))>0,]

merged_data[rowSums(merged_data[,-1]<0)==3,-1] <- 0 

merged_data
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
  Samples A1 A2  A3
1       a 98 65   1
3       c 50 85 116
4       d  0  0   0
5       f  6 99  35
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very muh for your reply. This looks to work! But the  minus values were not replace by 0. I started to work with R for some months ago, so can you maybe explain me what the 3 in line merged_data[rowSums(merged_data[,-1]<0)==3,-1] <- 0 mean, please?